# How to add multiple images to edit form using MongoDB in Sonata?

Tags: sonata-admin, symfony4, sonata, symfony-sonata, doctrine-mongodb

I'm trying to find out how I can have the edit action of a Document (Entity) that is using an array of Object IDs to store the ID of an image stored using GridFS. This is a one-to-many but using an array inside the Document, instead of a middle table.

So far I was able to add the following to my edit action:
[image: Images Manager for my News entity/document]

Here is the code I've used in the NewsAdmin configureFormFields():

```
$formMapper
        ->with('Images Manager')
        ->add(
            'cover_images',
            CollectionType::class,
            ['required' => true, 'label' => 'Cover Images'],
            [ 'admin_code' => 'admin.file' ]
        )
```

I have a controller and an action (@Route("/image/{id}", name="show_image")) that handles the display of images in the frontend using MongoDB GridFS. It uses the IDs stored in this array:
[image: Example of Array of Object IDs]